# How to chain two observables in angular2, when value of 1st observable need in 2nd one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I want chain two observable in Angular where output of the 1st observable is needed in second observable function as a parameter.

I have created a observable like this:

```
storeData(response: any): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    // storing the data in localstorage
    this.storage.ready().then(() => {
      this.storage.set('USERACCESSTOKEN', response.token).then(() => {
        this.storage.set('USERROLE', response.user_role).then(() => {
          delete response.token;
          this.storage.set('USERDATA', response).then(() => {
            this.setLoggedIn(true);
            observer.complete();
          })
        })
      })
    })
  });
}
```

I want to use in my login page like this:

```
login(form: any, event: Event): void {
  this.authService.otpVerify(form)
    .switchMap((data) => this.authService.storeData(data))
    .subscribe(response => {
        if(this.navCntrl.canGoBack())
          this.navCntrl.pop();
        else
          this.navCntrl.setRoot('TabsPage');
    }, (err)=>{
           console.log("your credentials doesn't match");
    });
}
```

Here from `otpVerify`, I will get response like that:

```
{
   "success"   : true,
   "message"   : "Login success",
   "token"     : "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJod…n19fQ.EMMT6wJeoF7Y52c3UQzgw3rkTY0WduGYq...........",
   "name"      : "Jony",
   "user_role" : "editor"
}
```

Here After correct credential checking, I want to check the **user_role** also. If user_role matches(editor or subscriber) from response then only it will go to `switchMap((data) => this.authService.storeData(data))` block else it will show **This role not permitted** dialog box & data also not been stored. [I haven't added this logic here as I don't know how to do that. but this is what I am looking for].

`otpVerify` function in the `AuthService` is something like that:

```
 otpVerify(body: any): Observable<any> {
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   return this.http.post(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT2 + 'login', body, this.options)
     .map(response => response.json())
     .catch(this._errorHandler);
 }
```

After this otp verification, I want to put condition also to see that it is a valid user or not. if everything goes fine, I will store the data, else show some error message. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: So you want to change the `login` method to make things work, right?

Comment: yes @AdrienBrunelat

Comment: What's wrong with the current code exactly? I don't have my angular environment set up and will have to assist you by head only.

Comment: Here data also storing but the problem is page is redirecting, don't know why. I want to write some logic in subscribe block, but it is redirecting me from flatmap return statement I believe.

Comment: Hm there is no apparent redirection in all the code you've posted, could you complete the post with the part of the code that does the redirection?

Comment: If the redirection is the issue, I'd say it's not coming from the TS code you've posted here. Maybe there is something with your router, or maybe there is an implicit link in your HTML code.

Comment: Sir, I just added my complete code what I want after subscribe

Comment: Which part of the code is responsible for checking user validity? Is it `storeData` or is it a brand new piece of code you want to add?

Comment: Ok, I'm getting confused, could you edit your original question and clarify the exact behavior you want in both cases (when auth fails and when it succeeds) mentionning the methods and their role in the use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, from what I understood of your recent edit, that would give us the following:

```
login(form: any, event: Event): void {
  this.authService.otpVerify(form)
    .switchMap(
      (data: any) => {
        if (data.user_role === "editor" || data.user_role === "subscriber") {
          return this.authService.storeData(data);
        } else {
          console.log("Insufficient privileges");
        }
      },
      (err) => console.log(err))
    .subscribe(() => {
      if (this.navCntrl.canGoBack()) {
        this.navCntrl.pop();
      } else {
        this.navCntrl.setRoot('TabsPage');
      }
    });
}
```

The code inside the switchMap checks the role and calls `storeData` only if the privileges are sufficient.

Comment: Working perfect sir, but don't know, why its not going to subscribe block.

Comment: page is redirecting before only.

Comment: Do you mean that when you have an user with the role "editor" or "subscriber", the redirection fails?

Comment: When everything fine, means role matches, it redirecting me to rootpage. Maybe its a Ionic issue. don't know.

Comment: Yeah looks like this is coming from the `navCntrl` part, which is something else.